# C++ How to differentiate std::cin to std::ifstream?

Tags: c++, ifstream, cin, difference

I am trying to make a simple comparison to find if istream is a std::cin or std::ifstream.

My pseudocode is something like that:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    void write(istream& is)
    {
        if(is == cin) // this does not work
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }
    }     
};
```

How can I proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Taking a `std::istream &` doesn't seem to be the best choice then. Overload the function. Really, though, changing the behaviour seems a bit suspect.

Comment: @chris How would overloading help? `std::cin` is an instance of `std::istream`.  What overload would detect `std::cin` and nothing else?

Comment: @cdhowie, I was thinking more the `std::ifstream` one catching that. The OP doesn't seem to indicate that `std::cin` in particular is special, just that they need to be differentiated between. I realize a file stream vs. any other stream isn't perfect.

Comment: What's your real requirement?  `cin` might represent a file... if it does should it start acting like `ifstream`?  (Actually, **any `iostream` can be linked with a `filebuf`**, just as if it were an `fstream`.  Chances are you want to test the `streambuf` object, not the `iostream`)

Comment: My goal is to detect the end of file of istream. When I use is.eof() works fine for ifstream, but when I change for cin I get stuck writting an infinity string on console.

Comment: `eof()` can look like it works sometimes for `std::fstream()` but in reality it is not doing the right thing. How is `.eof()` failing your with `std::cin`?

Comment: @marquesm91, First of all, rather than check for EOF only, check for success: `while (stream >> var)`. Second, you can enter EOF on consoles. It's most likely ctrl-Z on Windows and ctrl-D on Linux and Mac. If trying to read, say, an `int`, entering a letter or something will also exit the loop since the read failed.

Comment: Brillant @chris this explanation has clarified my mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `std::cin` is an instance of `std::istream`, you could compare the addresses of the two objects to see if they are equal:

```
if (&is == &std::cin)
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b6739b8dd2bf40))

However I would consider investigating if you can achieve your goal without doing this; switching logic based on the identity of the stream argument is not very clean and may inhibit future development or maintenance of this project.

Comment: this works perfectly! I'll try to find a best way, thank you!

Comment: What proofs this is defined behavior and in what C++ standards?

Comment: @Croll Taking the address of a function local and taking the address of a global are both defined behaviors, so both `&is` and `&std::cin` are defined. Comparing pointers is also defined behavior. So this code checks to see if `is` and `std::cin` are two different names for the same object, and the behavior is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to check if you have cin or not, but I had the same problem and my reason was: if I have cin, it means I'm in interactive mode, so I should give some useful information to cout.  While checking the address of cin with is will probably hopefully always work, I wouldn't really trust it...

Anyways, my solution was to slightly generalize and add an extra parameter with a reasonable default

```
void f(istream &i, ostream *o = nullptr) {
    if (o) {
        *o << "useful info...";
    }
    i >> important_variable;
}
```

This gives a slightly more general function, using the "pointer to parameter means optional parameter" idiom.  If you need cin for some other reason, then you may also look into specifically which properties of cin you need, and how to determine if your input stream possesses them.